# Переключение между вкладками браузера

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пишу приложение А на AngularJS. При клике на кнопку открывается новая вкладка с другим приложением Б. В приложении Б есть такая же кнопка, но переход на приложение А.

Делаю так:
`window.open('Приложение Б', '_blank');`

Когда я перехожу обратно на вкладку с приложением А и нажимаю на эту же кнопку открывается новое окно с приложением Б.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы был переход на уже открытую вкладку с приложением Б? Я правильно понимаю, что можно как-то ставить индексы вкладкам и уже совершать переход с их помощью?

Answer (score 1):

Есть второй параметр в функции `window.open`, который указывает вкладку, в которой открыть новое окно. Не работает корректно в `IE 11` и ниже.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0auLudf/3/).

```js
function openTab() {
  window.open('http://google.com', 'my-google'); // 'my-google' - здесь название вкладки
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openTab()">
 open
</button>
```